# Setting a tax class based on specific coupon in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, tax

This has been answered a while back but the filter is not working anymore. Not sure if it is deprecated or not. I am using both filters:

- `woocommerce_product_tax_class`
- `woocommerce_product_get_tax_class`

My function looks like:

```
function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
    $tax_class = "Zero rate";
    return $tax_class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
```

How can I set a tax class based on specific coupon in Woocommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3, the filter hook `woocommerce_product_tax_class` doesn't exist anymore, only new `woocommerce_product_get_tax_class` composite filter hook is available and works.

**There is multiple ways to set a tax class based on an applied coupon code** *(In both examples below, we set "Zero rate" tax class when a defined coupon code is applied)*:

1) Using `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` action hook, **the best way**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_tax_class_based_on_specific_coupon', 25, 1 );
function change_tax_class_based_on_specific_coupon( $cart ) {
    // Define your coupon code below
    if ( ! $cart->has_discount('summer') )
        return;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;


    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // We set "Zero rate" tax class
        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class("Zero rate");
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

2) Using `woocommerce_product_get_tax_class` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'change_tax_class_based_on_specific_coupon', 30, 2 );
function change_tax_class_based_on_specific_coupon( $tax_class, $product ) {
    // Define your coupon code below
    if( WC()->cart->has_discount('summer') )
        $tax_class = "Zero rate";

    return $tax_class;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: The first one worked great. Tried the second one too but nothing changed. Ill stick with the first one. Thanks for this!